# Azure AD B2C get users with custom attributes

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a problem with Azure AD B2C while I want to get users with their custom attribute set during creation. All is being done with Graph API (`string url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/" + "v1.0" + apiFunction;`). I registered user using API with custom attribute `"extension_08eedadaf5f*********53e8389608e_arvatoId": "1001"`, but when I call `/users` then I'm not getting this custom attribute in result. All I have are:
`{ "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity", "id": "40861b91-*********-b25889b0e685", "businessPhones": [], "displayName": "Nowe Testowe", "givenName": null, "jobTitle": null, "mail": null, "mobilePhone": null, "officeLocation": null, "preferredLanguage": null, "surname": null, "userPrincipalName": "NoweTestowe@*********.onmicrosoft.com" }`

How should I call the `/users` API to get user custom attribute value?

Comment: Hmm, I think that `beta` insted of `v1.0` solved this issue, now I'm getting all data including my custom attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `beta` endpoint returns all attributes of the user by default, and the `v1.0` endpoint hides user attributes that are not commonly used by default.